# fixed space of tensor representation

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of a finite group G over an algebraically closed field. If $V \otimes V$ has a fixed subspace acted by $G$, why should it be 1-dimensional? I really don't know how to think about this. I tried reasoning that there is a fixed space then $\phi(g)$ must have eigenvalue 1, but it's not contributive.

Comment: Dear Heidi, this definitely can't be true: if the only $G$-stable subspace of $V \otimes V$ were one-dimensional, then one could take its complement in $V \otimes V$. Do you mean that the elements in $G$ act trivially on the elements of this subspace?

Comment: @Akhil, yes, saying fixed is more than invariant. like you said, G act trivially on the elements of the subspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There need not be a fixed G-invariant subspace of dimension 1.  Consider the cyclic group G of order 4 and the representation on V=C given by g<sup>n</sup>↦sqrt(−1)<sup>n</sup>.  The corresponding representation on V⊗V ≅ C is given by g<sup>n</sup>↦(−1)<sup>n</sup>.  The fixed subspace has dimension 0, not 1.

On the other hand, if V is irreducible and V⊗V has a fixed G-invariant subspace of dimension larger than 0, then the dimension is exactly 1.  This follows from character theory:

$$[1,\chi \cdot \chi] = [ \bar \chi, \chi ] = \begin{cases} 0 & \chi \neq \bar \chi \\ 1 & \chi = \bar \chi \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks Jack, your answer in combination with this post: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/the-orthogonality-relations-for-representations-of-finite-groups/ helped me figuring out what I needed.